# Mostrar dados SQLITE entre datas - Android Studio (penso ser between)

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Boas, pretendo que o utilizador escolha os dados a mostrar entre as datas que ele escolhe. Já tentei de tudo mas ainda não consegui.

Ou seja o que pretendo é filtrar entre datas, mas o utilizador é que as tem que escolher. Já consegui com um comando SQL, mas ficava manual. Queria que fosse o utilizador a escolher as datas. Obrigado!

Código:

input.java

private EditText DataEdit;
    private EditText editDescricao;
    private Button botaoadicionar;
    private Button botaover;
    static EditText DateEdit;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.input);
    createDatabase();

    DataEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.iEditdata);
    editDescricao = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ieditDescricao);
    botaoadicionar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botaoadicionar);
    botaover = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botaover);
    botaoadicionar.setOnClickListener(this);
    botaover.setOnClickListener(this);
    DateEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.iEditdata);
    DateEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        // ver se fiz asneira...
        public void onClick(View v) {

            showTruitonDatePickerDialog(v);
        }
    });
}

protected void createDatabase(){
    db=openOrCreateDatabase("DadosDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabeladados(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, data DATE,descricao VARCHAR);");
}
protected void insertIntoDB(){
    String data = DataEdit.getText().toString().trim();
    String descricao = editDescricao.getText().toString().trim();
    if(data.equals("") || descricao.equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Preencha todos os campos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    String query = "INSERT INTO tabeladados (data,descricao) VALUES('"+data+"', '"+descricao+"');";
    db.execSQL(query);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Guardado com sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {


    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
private void mostrardados(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,output.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == botaoadicionar){
        insertIntoDB();
    }
    if(v==botaover){
        mostrardados();
    }
}
public void showTruitonDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}

public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

        DateEdit.setText(year + "-" + (month + 1) + "-" + day);
    }
}
```

}

output.java

public class output extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private EditText editDescricao;
    private EditText editTextId;
    private EditText editTextName;
    private Button botaoanterior;
    private Button botaoseguinte;

private static final String SELECT_SQL = "SELECT * FROM tabeladados";

```
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private Cursor c;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.output);
    openDatabase();
    editTextId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.oeditTextId);
    editDescricao = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.oeditDescricao);
    editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.oeditTextName);
    botaoanterior = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botaoanterior);
    botaoseguinte = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botaoseguinte);
    botaoseguinte.setOnClickListener(this);
    botaoanterior.setOnClickListener(this);
    c = db.rawQuery(SELECT_SQL, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    showRecords();

}

protected void openDatabase() {
    db = openOrCreateDatabase("DadosDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
}

protected void showRecords() {
    String id = c.getString(0);
    String data = c.getString(1);
    String add = c.getString(2);
    editTextId.setText(id);
    editDescricao.setText(add);
    editTextName.setText(data);

}
protected void moveNext() {
    if (!c.isLast())
        c.moveToNext();
    showRecords();
}
protected void movePrev() {
    if (!c.isFirst())
        c.moveToPrevious();
    showRecords();
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == botaoseguinte) {
        moveNext();
    }

    if (v == botaoanterior) {
        movePrev();
    }

}

public void voltar(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(output.this, input.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

input.xml

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="VER"
    android:id="@+id/botaover"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Adicionar"
    android:id="@+id/botaoadicionar"
    android:layout_above="@+id/botaover"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/iEditdata"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="114dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/botaoadicionar"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/ieditDescricao"
        android:hint="Descrição:"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iEditdata"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/iEditdata"
    android:id="@+id/Edithoras"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:hint="Total horas:" />
```

output xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/oeditTextName"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_height="161dp"
        android:id="@+id/oeditDescricao"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/botaoguardar"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Anterior"
    android:id="@+id/botaoanterior"
    android:layout_weight="0.20"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:text="Voltar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="voltar"
    android:id="@+id/botaovoltar"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Seguinte"
    android:id="@+id/botaoseguinte"
    android:layout_weight="0.31"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/botaovoltar"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/botaovoltar" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/totalhoras"
    android:layout_above="@+id/botaoanterior"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Comment: Você está armazenando a data como texto? Usualmente em SQLITE seria melhor usar REAL, junto das funções de julian date (que na verdade tem como base o proleptic gregorian calendar), ou INTEGER com funções de tempo Posix. Fazer com operações de string é sempre mais trabalhoso pro DB, além do desperdício de espaço.

Comment: db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabeladados(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, data DATE,descricao VARCHAR);");  -> Está no tipo data no SQLITE. O DateEdit é um popup que aparece um calendario pra inserir uma data no inputtext

Comment: Não existe DATE em SQLite. Salvo alguma extensão pra android usar isso. SQLite tem TEXT, INTEGER, REAL e BLOB só.

Comment: O que recomenda e como devo fazer?

Comment: Sem saber detalhes da aplicação, não saberia dizer o melhor caminho no seu caso. Só quis avisar para você entender que os tipos do SQLite são um pouco diferentes dos DBs mais comuns, e no caso de dinheiro e datas, é bom você ter algo mais especializado na sua aplicação para lidar com isso. Uma lida no manual do SQLite ajuda a dar uma noção, e na parte das funções de data tem como converter para INT ou FLOAT ao armazenar, e "desconverter" na hora do SELECT para mostrar como data mesmo.

Comment: Conhece algum exemplo do mesmo que eu quero fazer em algum lado? :/

Comment: Por enquanto, veja se consegue resolver com a solução do reginaldo, acho que é melhor depois você estudar e entender, só copiar um exemplo vai te dar mais duvidas do que solução. Depois que dominar melhor as funções de data, aí vc adapta.

Comment: A função que o caro Reginaldo deu funciona, mas pretendo é fazer select a dois inputs de data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como disse o Reginaldo acima, criando um botão pode resolver esse problema.

Crias as caixas de texto para o utilizador introduzir e depois vais buscar esse valor para efetuar a query de pesquisa à base de dados.

Não tenho a certeza da sintaxe mas deverá ser algo do género:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   String dataInicial = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dataInicial);
   String dataFinal = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dataFinal); // EditText é só um exemplo

   String query = "SELECT * FROM tabela 
   WHERE data BETWEEN " + dataInicial + " AND " + dataFinal;
   // aqui será o código para executar a query à BD.
   Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
   // depois terás de efetuar o tratamento dos dados
}
```

Comment: Devo colocar na parte do input certo?

Answer (score 0):

Assim funciona:

```
SELECT *
FROM tabela
WHERE datapesquisada BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31';
```

Comment: Boas, onde devo por este código? Quero que o utilizador escolha e não eu :/

Comment: Você pode criar uma caixa de dialogo pra ele informar a data inicial e data final e clicar em um botão. Portanto você colocaria o código no evento onclick do botão.

Comment: Penso ser esta a minha maior dificuldade! Sabe de algum exemplo onde possa aprender? Obrigado, vocês está a ajudar muito!

Comment: Você pode encontrar exemplos para todos os gostos e fins na web. Exemplo:
https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20create%20a%20dialog%20box%20in%20android%20example

Comment: Com o código que tenho em cima, acha que dá? Será que consegue dar um jeitinho? :/